How to create and download a patch from specific commit in Azure Devops Repos portal
I have an Azure Repo setup for my project. I am able to see the history of all commits from specific branch. I would like to download one of the commits as a patch. I found the option to cherry pick the changes into another branch, but no possibility just to create a zip file with changes and download it to my local pc.

Where in the Azure Devops portal can I find the option to create and download a patch from specific commit?

Dear @Arko the question is how to do it form Azure Devops Repository portal. I will edit my question so it is more clear.

After my workaround, I found that there is no default download option in Azure Devops portal for patch changes downloads. @fascynacja

After my workaround on your requirement, I found that there is no default download option in Azure Devops Repos portal to download a patch file after committing the changes.
Reference SO by @Levi Lu-MSFT for the relevant information in a detailed way.
As a workaround, I have cloned the repo into my VS code by clicking on Clone in VS Code option as shown below and the code will be cloned into your Vs code environment.
Or you can also clone it into the required platform accordingly by using the URL.
git clone <URL>

Open the terminal in Vs code with the respective path and execute the below commands for downloading the patch file.
Note: Generating a patch for specific commit: git format-patch
git checkout
git format-patch main --stdout > ./patchfile.patch
ls


